# Sharepoint Design is not automatical adopted by every page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like to change the sharepoint design by choosing a nice look in the settings... but my new design is just adopted by my settings page... Is this a sharepoint bug or is there a step missing?

Change look here:
[image: Here I change my look]

Design changed in my settings(Color is correct :)):
[image]

But my design on my landing page has not been changed... All other pages are also in old format...
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do these design changes in a master page, then apply that master page to all pages you want them to be shown on.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I suggest you to check whether your site which you want to apply a new theme on is associated with a hub site.

When you associate your site with a SharePoint hub site, it will inherit the look (theme) of the hub site, the hub site navigation bar will appear at the top of your site,
and more features or settings may be added such as additional navigation links, applications, or custom lists with specific columns.

How to check:
Go to home page->Settings->change the look:
[image][image]

If your site is associated with a hub site, you will see the prompt information like below:
[image]
Two workarounds for you:
(1) Go to your hub site to change the theme, and this site will automatically inherit the theme of the hub site.
(2) Disassociate the site from a hub site and then change the look again in your current site:
You can refer to [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/disassociate-a-sharepoint-site-from-a-hub-site-81b8dd5d-517b-4e0c-bdda-6f03937884aa) to disassociate the site from a hub site.